# Collecting data from subsites at root site level

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, sub-site

I have a team site with few subsites. Subsites are the projects that can be added at any time using template.

Every subsite has a task list.

**Is there a way to setup a main task list on a root page that collects and marges all tasks from subsites, including the one created after the root site was setup?**

I would like it to be displayed in a form of calendar or regular task timeline.

I have tried to use Content Search Web Part but it displays links and I would preferred to have it in a form of calendar or timeline.

I am new to sharepoint so I am not to sure if that is how it was designed to work.
I would appreciate any info, including links to resources(tutorials, informations) that would help me to setup what I have described.

TY

Answer (score 1):

You can think of using Content Query web part and query all tasks list within your site collection.

PS : http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/15735.aspx

You can get via coding as well :
[Show all tasks from user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40745/show-all-tasks-from-user)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 has a new service application "Task management service" which helps you to aggregate tasks from SharePoint sites, outlook, project server etc. You can try and leverage this service to aggregate tasks from different sites. [Here](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/mytasks-workmanagement-task-aggregation-apis-sharepoint-online/) is a very good reference.

Comment: this doesn't apply for SharePoint online. please revisit your answer